# How can I connect to SMTP using TELNET?

Tags: smtp, gmail, command, telnet

I'm trying to connect to GMAIL SMTP via TELNET.

When I type the command

```
mail from: guilerme18@gmail.com
```

it shows me the message

```
530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. N72sm4504959yhh.21.
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only connect to Google's mail services via an encrypted connection.  TLS is the encryption scheme being requested.  Since you're using Telnet, this is not something you're going to be easily able to do.

(pretty much you'd have to encrypt as you type and be able to read the encrypted response or decrypt it to understand it).

> If your client does not support SMTP authentication, you won't be able to send mail through your client using your Gmail address.
>
> TLS: TLS (Transport Layer Security) is a way of changing data such as your username and password into code as it travels across the Internet, so that the data will be secure and private. With mail delivery, TLS begins with an unsecured connection to the mail servers, and then upgrades to a secure connection once information is sent.

Source: [Connecting other clients to Google Mail](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287)

EDIT

I guess one should also ponder the question "why?"

Comment: I suppose you could use telnet over SSL, then?

Comment: Nope. SSL is not the encryption scheme required.  They need you to be able to perform TLS.  (TLS is the successor to SSL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)

Comment: Erm, when I say SSL I mean TLS. My bad.

Comment: I guess it's worth a shot, but at that point, why not just use a mail program?  I mean even mutt supports IMAP and TLS and is totally text based.

Answer (score 2):

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect smtp.gmail.com:587 -crlf -ign_eof
```

Using openssl would be better.

Comment: This is the way to do it!

Comment: Exactly what I needed, couldn't use telnet to test Amazon SES as it required TLS

Comment: ANd how do you enter your password authentification on telnet then?